# Tikz: Rectangle Split Inner Separations

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, split, shapes

Using `tikz` and `tikzshapes`, two split rectangles are created. Is it possible to have different inner separations for each part?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=left}]
\node[rounded corners=0.5ex,inner sep=0.75ex,rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split part align={left},rectangle split part fill={gray,yellow}]
{
Energy Conversion in an IC Engine

\nodepart{two}
Chemical Energy $\rightarrow$ Heat Energy $\rightarrow$ Mechanical Energy
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Desired output (in which the bottom part has more inner separation):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add an invisible high object.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=left}]
\node[rounded corners=0.5ex,inner sep=0.75ex,rectangle split, rectangle split
parts=2, rectangle split part align={left},rectangle split part
fill={gray,yellow}]
{
Energy Conversion in an IC Engine

\nodepart{two}
\vphantom{$\vcenter{\vspace{2em}}$}%
Chemical Energy $\rightarrow$ Heat Energy $\rightarrow$ Mechanical Energy
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `tcolorbox` package is designed to make boxes like this one.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    boxrule=0pt, left=.5ex, width=.75\textwidth,
    colback=yellow, colframe=gray, coltitle=black,
    title=Energy Conversion in an IC Engine
]
Chemical Energy $\rightarrow$ Heat Energy $\rightarrow$ Mechanical Energy
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]